# Can I set the value of decimal variable within an extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have created a `void` extension method which can be used with `decimal` data types. I wanted to be able to modify the `this` parameter variable inside the scope of the method. This is the code for my extension method:

```
public static void SetAndConvertIfHasValue(this decimal assignTo, double? valueToAssign)
{
    if (valueToAssign.HasValue)
        assignTo = (decimal)valueToAssign.Value;
    else
        assignTo = 0m;
}
```

However, when I call it:

```
data.MyDecimalToSet.SetAndConvertIfHasValue(nullableDouble);
```

`data.MyDecimalToSet` is not set to the value in `nullableDouble` if it has one.

In debug if I step into the extension method, `assignTo` is changed to the correct value, this change just doesn't bubble up to `data.MyDecimalToSet`.

At this point I have decided to use a standard method rather than an extension method as a solution to this problem, however I was curious as to why this doesn't work? And whether there is a way around it, or if it simply is impossible?

Comment: If you want to get crazy, you can create an extension method that takes an `Expression<decimal>` in addition to the `double?`, unwraps it and sets the property using a bit of reflection. Then you would call it on the base object rather than the property, like so: `data.SetAndConvertIfHasValue(d => d.MyDecimalToSet, nullableDouble)`. It's uglier and slower, but it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because when you pass a variable to a method, a copy of that variable is passed. When you operate on that copy, you will only be changing the copy.

Note that this will happen regardless of whether the variable is a reference or a value type. However, if you pass a reference type, you can change the *contents* of the reference type, since the reference passed to the method will be copied, but it will still reference the original object.

(`decimal` is a value type, so that last point does not apply to it.)

You are doing it the right way if you use a standard method instead.

Comment: I thought this was the reason. I tried passing it as `ref` but that is not supported with extension methods.

Comment: Don't use "stack" and "heap" in these sorts of explanations as they are implementation details. Copy and reference semantics would be better. In any case, even if a reference type were used here, the same problem would occur because you can't modify variables/properties/fields that are passed in unless they are passed with `ref` or `out`. It has nothing, therefore, to do with value types vs. reference types.

Comment: @siride I presume, like `ref`, you can't use `out` in extension methods?

Comment: @GaryEmery: correct (because in the CLR, `ref` and `out` are the exact same thing -- only in C# does the compiler enforce a difference with the `OutAttribute`). More importantly, though, is that you can't pass properties to extension methods or any methods as `ref`/`out`.

Comment: @siride I've corrected my answer somewhat.